# Google Chrome Other Bookmarks Toolbar Object Location

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I'm trying to figure out a way to access the section of the bookmarks toolbar where 'Other Bookmarks' is stored.  I would like to place something next to it.

Is this hard coded into Chrome or can I access it through the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the "**bookmarks**" permission in the extension manifest to use the bookmarks API. For example:

**manifest.json**

```
{
        "name": "My extension",
        ...
        "permissions": [
          "bookmarks"
        ],
        ...
}
```

Read complete documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks).

Comment: Useless comment, I'm already sieving through the documentation.  You have merely told me how to allow my extension to access the bookmarks API.